# Is "I was heard" correct to write?

Tags: grammar, british-english, literature

I've just started to translate BLOOD by Maggie Gee into my native language (Vietnamese). In the very first paragraphs of the book, I came across a difficult line, which reads

```
Dad is dead, and I’ve never liked him. Yes, it’s true, I was heard ‘making threats’
```

I am confused as to what it means in English the phrase *I was heard ‘making threats’*

Does anybody know? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I understand, it means....."others heard me making threats..."

Comment: The fact that "making threats" is in quotes indicates that what he was heard to say is open to some interpretation, so e.g. a bystander may have interpreted his words as more threatening than he intended.